# How to add a data from web page which was protected with username & password to google spread sheets by using importhtml function

Tags: google-sheets

How to add a data from web page which was protected with username & password to google spread sheets by using importhtml function.

I am having username & password fro the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please ask a good question + share your code with us. Also please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/)